# How to write async with $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async.js

I am doing something like this

```
$.getJSON(url1, function(response1){
if(response1.status == 'success'){
    $.getJSON(url2, function(response2){
        if(response2.status == 'success') {
            $.getJSON(url3, function(response3){
                if(response3.status == 'success') {
                    //final code here
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

I have heard about async library like https://github.com/caolan/async#series
How do i implement this in this condition?

Comment: You don't implement that! You do it the way you're doing it, and if you'd like it to look cleaner, you use deferreds and promises to do the same thing.

Comment: The code you have is already asynchronous, If you want a cleaner code as @adeneo suggested you can use the differed/promise api. To test the async nature if you want you can add a `console.log('after post')` after the `$.getJson()` call and  `console.log('after callback')` before the `if(response2.status == 'success')` statements

Comment: To use jQuery Deferreds as suggested above, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is already using asynchronous processing model. So you don't have to use any other library to make it asynchronous.

[$.getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is a utility method which uses [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to sent and receive data from the server. $.ajax uses XmlHttpRequest to sent/receive data which is built using asynchronous processing model.

To test the async nature if you want you can add a console.log('after post') after the $.getJson() call and console.log('after callback') before the if(response2.status == 'success') statements.

If you check your console after sending the request you will find that `after post` appears before `after callback` which means that the script execution continued without waiting for the response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to make a synchronous call (blocking the browser until it completes) or just have a "cleaner" way of starting one `getJSON` after the other is done (without nesting it in the callback)? As others already pointed out, the ajax calls are already synchronous to each other.

For the first option, look at the more general [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (you can set `async` to `false` in the arguments). For the second, you can just create a recursive utility function:

```
function chain(list,index,callback,errorCallback) {
    if ( index == list.length )
        return callback();
    $.getJSON(list[index])
        .done(function() {
            chain(list,index+1,callback);
        })
        .fail(errorCallback);
}
chain([url1, url2, url3],0,function() {
    //final code here
},function() {
    //error handling here (in any of the calls)
});
```